# How can I have something on every slide without having to manualy insert it on every slide?

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I want a link to my table of contents slide on the bottom of every slide. It would be like a very basic breadcrumbs. Currently, there is only the navigation arrows on every slide. Could I use an iframe or some other contraption?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did:

```
<!-- Wrap the entire slide show in a div using the "reveal" class. -->
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="header-right" style="z-index: 100;">
    <a href="http://url">Link to URL</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Wrap all slides in a single "slides" class -->
  <div class="slides">
```

This gave me a link in the upper right corner of every slide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a div-container (with position:absolute) between the reveal-class and slide-class.